# Visual Studio for Mac: How to run tests with x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I just discovered that in Visual Studio for Mac that running tests from the Unit Tests tab is not in x64. However my entire solution really depends on x64?

I can't seem to find a way to do this?

Comment: I believe that is still "broken" within the IDE as you can not set a 64bit custom "mode" and have it actually be applied to the IDE based test runs , report it as a bug over at http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/ (FYI: The cmd-line for nunit3-console.exe is broken the opposite way as you can not override mono (via mono32 or `--arch=32`)  or `nunit3-console.exe` (`--x86`) to get NUnit tests to run in a 32 bit env, not that it matters much anymore w/ the MacOS 32bit deprecation)

Comment: I created an issue https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/357275/64-bit-unit-testing-is-not-supported.html and you can vote it up.

Comment: Did you try changing the project so it compiles x64. That should force the tests to be run with x64.

Comment: @MattWard unfortunately that don’t work. The settings doesn’t seem to get picked up by the VS unit testing tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it manually until the new version of vs4mac is released with the fix by removing the mono32 executable and creating a link from mono64 to mono32. This will remove support for 32 bits in Mono for your installation, but all the tools and applications will still work as they should already be using the 64 bits version by default (*mono* already links to *mono64*).

```
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/
$ sudo rm mono32
$ sudo ln -s mono64 mono32
```